# Why Puppet uses different ruby version

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have the following error after installation of puppet:

```
# puppet master --version
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- json (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/module.rb:3
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/files.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/templatewrapper.rb:1
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/scope.rb:6
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/methods.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/ast/method_call.rb:2
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/ast.rb:115
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser/parser.rb:11
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/parser.rb:4
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet.rb:282
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/puppet/util/command_line.rb:12
    from /usr/bin/puppet:7:in `require'
    from /usr/bin/puppet:7
```

My configuration:
OS: Centos 6.5
Puppet: puppet-server-3.8.7-1.el6.noarch

```
# rvm list

 rvm rubies

   ruby-2.1.0 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.4.1 [ x86_64 ]

# ruby --version
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

Why puppet uses ruby 1.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rvm isn't loaded in the environment of the user running puppet, look at the `.bashrc` and `.profile` of the user where you ran `rvm list` and then look at the same for the puppet user.  It looks like the puppet user isn't rvm aware and is instead using the system ruby.

You want to see something like the following in your `.profile`:

```
$ cat ~/.profile

export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin" # Add RVM to PATH for scripting

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

It could be that you've only setup rvm for a single user rather than system wide.  You may only want it set up per-user but in that case it does need to be set up for the user running puppet.

Comment: Thanks Mike. However issue here is that user puppet has default shell nologin:        puppet:x:52:52:Puppet:/var/lib/puppet:/sbin/nologin . How in this case should I modify $PATH for it?

Comment: @pitmod where is rvm installed?  This should still be solvable, that said maybe rvm isn't the best solution for this case, is this a production server?  You may be better off just setting 2.4.1 as your system ruby.